# REACT NATIVE : height size items

Tags: android, ios, react-native

in native react, if we define a list of items whose each item has a size X. on an android device, the size of each item is converted into "dp". As a result a tablet displays 10 items while a smartphone only 6 but the size of the items is strictly the same on each device. On IOS, the size of items is converted to a pixel. The result is not the same as on android devices. is there a way to have a size that works like "dp" on androïd? other than PixelRatio (not accurate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-dimensions ,that will work